# resolv.conf issue with two private domains

Tags: linux, domain-name-system

I have peered private networks and working routing between them, but no DNS forwarding that I know of or that I can easily configure.  I need a local linux machine to resolve an FQDN from the other domain.  For ex.

- Domain A -- myprivate.local, nameserver 10.1.1.1
- Domain B -- myother.com, nameserver 100.1.1.1

My auto-generated resolv.conf file is as following:

```
nameserver 10.1.1.1
nameserver 100.1.1.1
```

.. but this doesn't resolve host1.myother.com, i.e.

```
nslookup host1.myother.com
```

How should my resolv.conf look?  Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: Auto-generated by what ?

Answer (score 0):

You're going about it wrong. A nameserver (resolver) should be able to resolve any and all queries.
Currently all of your queries are going to `10.1.1.1` and it is giving a valid response back (DNS does not exist)

To do what you're proposing you need a 3rd DNS server (I assume running on 127.0.0.1)
The 3rd DNS server would `forward` `myprivate.local` to `10.1.1.1` and also `forward` `myother.com` to `100.1.1.1` It might also forward other requests elsewhere

Note `.local` is reserved domain for self assigned and multicast addresses, I think it's RFC8244, I think it's the same RFC as the 169.254 ip addresses and REALLY shouldn't be resolved via traditional DNS servers

----edit----

If you take a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/589349/dnsmasq-config-forwarding-queries-for-domain-net-but-keeping-local-domain-net-qu you'll see how others are using dnsmasq (which is very common on most linux distro's) to forward requests in the way I'm describing above. If you're wanting specific domains to go to one dns server and everything else to the other then you'll only need one override.
Hopefully that helps give you a working example

Comment: Thanks Timothy.  Sounds like a private DNS is in order.  The .local is just my poor example -- just learning this, so no surprising it was wrong.